# Android notification disappear on marshmallow and lollipop after few seconds

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, android-notifications, android-6.0-marshmallow

Android Firebase notifications disappear automatically on marshmallow and lollipop version after few seconds. How to keep notification on this version till user tap on it or clear manually?

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    String channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
            .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                "Channel human readable title",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe (it's hard to tell with supplied info) the problem is in

```
notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */
```

If you always set notification id to `0` the every new notification will override the old one, [see specs.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager#notify(int,%20android.app.Notification))

> If a notification with the same id has already been posted by your application and has not yet been canceled, it will be replaced by the updated information.

Comment: But it's happening only on marshmallow and lollipop version. On nougat version its working as expected.